# How to understand these sentences about CPL in Intel Volume 3

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

Intel V3 **4.6 Access Rights** part contains these sentences below:

> Some operations implicitly access system data structures with linear addresses; the resulting accesses to those 
>   data structures are supervisor-mode accesses regardless of CPL. Examples of such accesses include the following: 
>   accesses to the global descriptor table (GDT) or local descriptor table (LDT) to load a segment descriptor; accesses 
>   to the interrupt descriptor table (IDT) when delivering an interrupt or exception; and accesses to the task-state 
>   segment (TSS) as part of a task switch or change of CPL. All these accesses are called implicit supervisor-mode 
>   accesses regardless of CPL.

**How to understand "*regardless of CPL*"** for CPL is crucial and it must be taken seriously.

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is. Is the problem that don't understand what the English phrase "regardless of"  means? Or do you not understand something else?

Answer (score -1):

Ultimately, what it is saying is that sometimes pages where CPL=3 can be accessed with restricted supervisor privileges instead of user privileges.

In the paragraph before the one you quote, it says "...; accesses made
while CPL < 3 are supervisor-mode accesses, while accesses made while CPL = 3 are user-mode accesses."

Then, starting at the end of your quote and going to the end of the paragraph, it says " All these accesses are called implicit supervisor-mode
accesses regardless of CPL. Other accesses made while CPL < 3 are called explicit supervisor-mode accesses."

So, basically, this is the situation:

```
if a program is running with supervisor privileges then
   if the page is flagged for implicit supervisor access then
      access is implicit supervisor mode
   else if CPL<3 then 
      access is explicit supervisor mode
   else (i.e when CPL=3) 
      access is user mode

else if a program is running with user privileges then
   if CPL<3 then no access is allowed
   else (i.e when CPL=3) access is user mode
```

When you look at the list of rules further down the page, you will see that decisions on behavior are based on both access mode {explicit supervisor | implicit supervisor |user} and CPL {<3 | =3}. So, ultimately, CPL is not ignored.